# Handbrake generated M4V/MP4 files with Flash Streaming Server over RTMP

Tags: flash, video, streaming, rtmp, transcoding

We are attempting to transcode some video to a format suitable for our Flash Streaming Server. In the past we have used Adobe Media Encoder (AME) CS4, but we are working with *.VOB files this time, and AME CS4 does not support them.

We are attempting to use Handbrake now, as it has great support for h.264 and MP4 files. Unfortunately while the files play wonderfully on our local machines, they do not stream from the Flash streaming server over RTMP. The files come out of Handbrake with a *.m4v extension.

Our old files out of AME CS4 are *.MP4's with h.264 and AAC audio. I can see no differences in video or audio codecs which leads me to believe it may be a container format problem.

Has anyone had success with Handbrake and Flash Streaming? We are attempting to use Handbrake because it does an excellent job of batch encoding files and produces good quality files.

**EDIT**

I should probably note that we are encoding fairly **large** files. They are approximately 1GB right now, and could be even larger in the future. I don't think this should be a problem, but just throwing it out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COOL, what a stupid problem to have.

It turns out that the answer is... you can't have videos in subfolders of "vod" on a default Flash streaming server. You may be able to do it with additional configuration, but that is something we're lacking at the moment.

Now I will be answering my own question. There goes your potential points, Stackoverflow crowd!

Comment: Do you happen to know how to enable Closed Caption support on an output file in Handbrake? I can see where to set it to `Forced Only` or `Burned In`, but these options won't allow me to turn them **off** or **on** as needed.

Comment: I do not, sorry. I've never used Handbrake to convert a file with subtitles. Good luck!

Comment: So the m4v extension was not an issue?

Comment: This was awhile ago but if I remember correctly m4v was not the problem. You just can't make subfolders in `vod`.